# Can mysqldump get me the database but only *some of the data?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking through [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) and not seeing anything that would allow me to get a copy of the db, but to *not include the data from some specified tables (however I DO want the tables - just not the data in them).

In other words, if I have a db that has 5 tables (a,b,c,d,e) all filled with data and I want to grab a copy of the full schema but I don't want the data from tables c and e, does mysqldump have facility for such a process or am I forced to make a full copy and then manually delete the data I don't want from the copy after the fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make 2 dumps one with [no data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) and one with [only data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info)

#### Edit

So the process is to dump the structure **only** with the *no-data* flag.
Then you dump the data **only** with the *no-create-info* flag.

You'll have 2 files one containing only the database structure and the other one containing only the data. Then you can use those files to recreate a database.

Of course, you can filter by table name to get only the tables you need.

#### Edit 2

To use the files generated by the dump just use this syntax

```
mysql -u username -p -D database -h hostname < dump_file
```

Comment: sorry... how does that help me? once I have these two, what's my path to including the data from the tables I want back into the dataless db?

Comment: @GeniaS. I updated my answer to make it clearer. I hope